# ActiveMQ fail-over of producer and consumer with a shared directory doesn't happen

Tags: activemq-classic, high-availability, failover, shared-directory

We have two ActiveMQ(version 5.10.0) instances running and I am using the shared storage to achieve HA.
However I am unable to see failover happening for the producer and consumer(s).

ActiveMQ broker-1 runs on IP1 and broker-2 on IP2
And under the activemq.xml of configuration I have modified persistence adapter to use a shared directory which is present on IP1.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="\\IP1\shared-directory\for activemq\data"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

Both in producer and consumer sides I am using following JNDI configurations to get the connections and build sessions,etc.

> jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial = ..........ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = failover:(tcp://IP1:61616,tcp://IP2:61616)?randomize=false
connectionFactoryNames = myConnectionFactory
queue.requestQ = my.RequestQ
```

**Interesting part is** :

When I start this broker pair, I see that one of the brokers becomes master.
When I start the producer, which puts the message on the Q (say producer has put 100 messages on the Q). While my producer is still running; I shutdown master broker, hence slave broker acquires the file-lock and becomes master.When I open the webconsole I see that 100 messages are still there on the Q. Even though producer is running it no longer puts any messages on this Q.

Similar to this for the consumers also.
Consumer was picking messages from the Q, this Q has say 100 messages unconsumed when master failed, now master goes down, slave becomes master, I see 100 messages are still unconsumed, but the consumer does not pick any message from the Q.

I waited them to failover for a long time.(>10 mins.)
Can any one please suggest what configuration am I missing ?

I am copy pasting producer and consumer as is (I've copied this from ActiveMQ in action book with minor modifications).

**Producer**

```
public class Producer {

    private static String brokerURL = "failover:(tcp://IP1:3389,tcp://IP2:3389)";
    private static transient ConnectionFactory factory;
    private transient Connection connection;
    private transient Session session;
    private transient MessageProducer producer;

    private static int count = 10;
    private static int total;
    private static int id = 1000000;
    private String jobs[] = new String[] { "suspend", "delete" };

    public Producer() throws JMSException {
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(null);
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        while (total < 1000) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                producer.sendMessage();
            }
            total += count;
            System.out.println("Sent '" + count + "' of '" + total
                    + "' job messages");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            }
        }
        producer.close();

    }

    public void sendMessage() throws JMSException {
        int idx = 0;
        while (true) {
            idx = (int) Math.round(jobs.length * Math.random());
            if (idx < jobs.length) {
                break;
            }
        }
        String job = jobs[idx];
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("JOBS." + job);
        Message message = session.createObjectMessage(id++);
        System.out.println("Sending: id: "
                + ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject() + " on queue: "
                + destination);
        producer.send(destination, message);
    }
}
```

**Consumer**

```
public class Consumer {

    private static String brokerURL = "failover:(tcp://IP1:3389,tcp://IP2:3389)";
    private static transient ConnectionFactory factory;
    private transient Connection connection;
    private transient Session session;

    private String jobs[] = new String[] { "suspend", "delete" };

    public Consumer() throws JMSException {
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        for (String job : consumer.jobs) {
            Destination destination = consumer.getSession().createQueue(
                    "JOBS." + job);
            MessageConsumer messageConsumer = consumer.getSession()
                    .createConsumer(destination);
            messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new Listener(job));
        }
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

}
```

Just one more thing: 
**I am more interested in consumer failover than producer.**
One more observation is : Consumer stops and comes to the command prompt abruptly.

Thank you.
-JE

Comment: Is the consumer actually connected to broker IP2?  You can see this from the Active Consumers list for Q on the web console...

Comment: @Tim : NO, I do not see any of the consumers connected to the Q. According to my understanding automatically they should be able to connect to the new master. As we are using failover prototocol. java.naming.provider.url = failover:(tcp://IP1:61616,tcp://IP2:61616)?randomize=false

Comment: What value are you using for the `WireFormat.maxInactivityDuration`?  Your consumers won't fail over to the backup until they determine that the connection is dead, which won't happen till that inactivity duration elapses.

Comment: @Tim: I tried adding the maxInactivityDuration but didn't find any change in the behavior.

Comment: Added the code for better understanding.

Comment: Is that code your actual code?  Because your failover URI doesn't match the one you posted in your original question and repeated in your comment above, and I don't see any reference to JNDI in the code you posted.  At a minimum, I'd have expected the two TCP transports to be wrapped in parentheses (ignoring the `randomize=false` URI option), and the fact that they're not might very well be the reason it's not working.

Comment: @Tim : I've also tried adding parentheses but behavior does not change. And I've hardcoded the broker URLs to make it simpler instead of referring to the JDNI.

Comment: If the consumer is stopping abruptly, try to determine why and when. Add logging and/or turn on debug/trace logging for the activemq client.  Try also setting up something that is standard and not your own code, such as doing this test with Jmeter.  That way you know where to focus.